# how should I set <PrintWhenExperssion> value true or false from java code

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to set

```
<printWhenExpression>![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(true)]]</printWhenExpression>
```

to `Boolean.valueOf(false)` when I fill the report according to some conditions. This means I want to set value '`false`' in `<printWhenExpression>` at run time. Can any one help me for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having hard coded value `Boolean.valueOf(true)/Boolean.valueOf(false)` use a variable which is evaluation to a boolean:

```
Boolean.valueOf(someVariableOfTypeBoolean)
```

or

```
Boolean.valueOf(someMethodThatReturnsBoolean())
```